# How to save PictureBox image when control is not visible?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

So this is the code for saving:

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Bitmap (*.BMP)|*.bmp|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

                MessageBox.Show("Vasa slika je uspjesno spremljena");

            }
        }

    }
```

pictureBox1.Image == null when it's not visible. Like it doesn't exist when it's not visible.

pictureBox1.Image contains my image, but it must not be visible for design reasons. Is there any simple way to save it while not visible, or hide it behind program window while visible?

Comment: what is wrong with current implementation?

Comment: pictureBox1.Image == null when it's not visible. Seems stupid, I know, but it's true. It's like my pictureBox doesn't exist at all when it's not visible.

Comment: agree with @sneakthief. But suggest to set size(1,1) and location(-1,-1)

Comment: Just tried with a simple form and a picturebox1. If `picturebox1.Visible = false;` the `picturebox1.Image` is not null. Are you sure that is not your code that set the image to null somewhere (for example handling VisibleChanged event?)

Comment: I'm 100% sure that code is not setting it's value to null. Setting its position outside visible range or setting visibility to false will cause this problem however. I've set the size to 1x1 and put it on the visible place and it works. I'll satisfy with this for now. Thanks people